# Is using the method driver.close() required?

Tags: java, selenium, window, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Let's say

1. I have a `window 1`. I have performed an event on the `window 1` that makes `window 2` to appear.
2. Now I switched to the `window 2` and clicked a button on it which closes `window 2`.

If I use `driver.close()` after I performed an event which caused the window to close, sometimes it throws `NoSuchWindowException`.

If I don't use the `driver.close()` then sometimes  `driver.getWindowHandles().size()` returns `2` even when there is *only one window* and I have waited enough time to number of windows become `1`.

I refresh `driver.getWindowHandles()` and check for the `driver.getWindowHandles().size()` to become `1` but it doesn't sometimes.

My question is, do I need to use the method `driver.close()` after I clicked the button that caused the window to close? How to use the `driver.close()` correctly.

**EDIT:** Yes, it is a problem. If selenium doesn't realize `window2` has been closed, it keeps returning the handles to be `2`. Suppose that I closed `window2` and switched back to `window1` and performed an event which opens `window3`. Now I want to switch to `window3`. Here is the problem because Selenium still think `windows2` exists and now there are three windows according to the Selenium.

```
String window1Handle = driver.getWindowHandle();
//Now I have oepend window3
//According to the Selenium there are 3 windows
// So driver.getWindowHandles().size() returns 3
 for (String window : driver.getWindowHandles() {
        if (!window.equals(window1Handle)) {
                  driver.switchTo().window();
```

***The above line may throw exception because driver is trying to switch to a window which has already been closed"***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***I wrote a method that is working pretty good for me.***

```
public static boolean letWebDriverRealizeThisWindowHasBeenClosed(WebDriver driver,
            String closedWindowHandle) {
        /**
         * to avoid infinite loop, do write a break when definite time has been passed
         */
        /**
         * Generally, this method returns true given that window is closed
         */

    boolean isWebDriverRealized = false;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long end = start + (30 * 1000); //30 seconds
    while (!isWebDriverRealized 
            && System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
        try {
            driver.switchTo().window(closedWindowHandle);
        } catch (NoSuchWindowException nswe) {
            isWebDriverRealized = true;
        }
    }
    return isWebDriverRealized;
}
```

If this method returns `true`, then it means `WebDriver` has realized that window has been `closed`. `driver.getWindowHandles.size()` returns the **correct number of windows** once the above method returns `true`.

Answer (score 3):

No you don't need to perform a driver.close(), if anything is left open, when you perform a driver.quit() at the end of your test WebDriver will clean up and make sure that everything is shut down correctly.

Selenium can track how many windows are open, if you are seeing window handles for windows that are closed that sounds like a potential bug.  Bear in mind that it may take some time for Selenium to realise that the window has been closed, you could try using an explicit wait to wait for the count of window handles to drop back down to 1, you'll need to add the following ExpectedCondition:

```
  public static ExpectedCondition<Boolean> numberOfWindowsToBe(final int numberOfWindows) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
      @Override
      public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.getWindowHandles().size() == numberOfWindows;
      }
    };
  }
```

Then you can use it by doing:

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15, 100);
    wait.until(numberOfWindowsToBe(1));
```

or you could just try closing the window by performing a driver.close() and catching the NoSuchWindowException e.g.

```
try{
    driver.close();
} catch(NoSuchWindowException ignored){
    System.out.println("Window already closed");
}
```

This should give Selenium the kick it needs to realise that the window has been closed (Although to be honest I wouldn't bother).

****EDIT****

So it sounds like the problem is that you have multiple window handles and you don't know which one is the window that has been closed, and which one is your newly opened window.  One workaround would be to track the window handles in a Map.  Every time you open a new window store the window handle in the map like this:

```
Map<String, String> openedWindows = new HashMap<String, String>();
openedWindows.put("Window 1", driver.getWindowHandle());
```

You will then know which window handle is associated with your window, you can then remove windows from the map as they are closed.  You will know which handles that are still being reported are actually closed and which are being reported in error.

Really this sounds like a bug in Selenium window handling and I would suggest you raise an issue on the issue tracker with a minimal test script that reproduces the problem.  Of course the other option above is still valid, try and close the window but catch the exception and see if that gives Selenium the kick it needs to remove it from the list of window handles.

Comment: Sometimes selenium doesn't realize the window has been closed, it keeps returning 2 even when I have waited for enough time.

Comment: You can then try forcing the issue by performing a close and catching the Exception.  Is it a problem for you to just leave the window handle there?  driver.quit() will clean up and destroy everything when your test finishes anyway.

Comment: To be honest I don't see the point in doing what you are doing.  Why have you got a while loop continually trying to switch to the window, surely once is enough.  If it's already gone I would suggest you would be better served by tracking the windows you want to use rather than worrying about a reference to a window you no longer want to interact with.

Comment: It is important to let the WebDriver realize some window has been closed. If driver tries to switch to a closed window, `NoSuchWindowException` is thrown and `driver.getWindowHandles().size()` returns the correct number of windows. In my method, I am forcing the driver to update the window handles to the correct number.

Comment: No, it's important to know *which window you are trying to switch to*.  What you are saying is a bit like saying it's important for Selenium to know that elements have gone stale rather then throwing a StaleElementException when you try to access a stale element.  You should know what you are trying to drive and your test should not be trying to access windows that are not expected to be there.

Comment: Why to let the *driver* have a reference to a window that is no longer available? Via method, I am passing the `window handle` of the closed window, and letting *driver* know window has been closed,  don't have reference to this window any more.

Comment: Because, to be blunt, it doesn't matter.  The driver has a reference to lots of things that you don't use and in some cases things that aren't implemented for that driver.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is a bit of a hack...but I've never seen something like what you are describing, so I think its worth a try.  Change this code:

```
driver.switchTo().window();
```

to something like this:

```
try{
   driver.switchTo().window();
   perform action that will throw error
   return; //will return if error wasn't thrown
catch(Error thrown if on bad window){
   //continue in your for loop to switch to the next window;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same exact issue You are facing.**

Before i perform an action which pops up second window, i intiated

```
String window = driver.getWindowHandle();
```

Later i clicked link 1 which populates window 2 and i switch to that window

```
driver.switchTo().window(window name);
```

i performed my action in Window 2 and when i click the link in Window 2 my window closes automatically and **if i use `driver.close()` it wont happen as webdriver will throw error as u said**

so instead of trying to close the second window, i try to switch back to window 1 with

```
driver.switchTo().window(window);
```

This is because since window 2 is closed automatically and since the control does not pass to window 1 the error will happen.. **So there is no necessity to close window 2.** instead we can switch back to our default window and continue or close the default window..

Comment: His question also has the additional problem of switching to a third window that opens

Answer (score -1):

No, you don't need to do that. Because second window is already close, and if you will use method `driver.close()` it will close your first window and the browser itself(because there is only one tab left in browser window).

Comment: driver.close() closes the window which driver has currently focus on . It will throw an NoSuchWindowException if the window that driver has focus has already been closed.

Answer (score -1):

Its depends upon the Window,

1. some Window close while click on outside Window content, in that case no need of `driver.close()` method.
2. but for some Window, click on outside the Window content, Window unable to close (i.e. Window gets close after click on close button), in that case need to close such Window using the`driver.close()` method.

Comment: behaviors also vary browser specific, you are using IE driver then 2nd case gets happen need to close window by using driver.close() method.